# Why I need re- reference dll on major change in library

Tags: c#, .net, indexer

I implemented a indexer in my library Base.dll

```
namespace Base
{
public class BOCollection<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public BOCollection() : base() { }
    public BOCollection(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
    public BOCollection(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(comparer) { }
    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                return base[key];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                base[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now this change is forcing me to re-compile or re-reference Base.dll in all other library. 
I cleaned my web application but problem is still there.
I am getting error : 
Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 Base.get_Child()'.

But once I re-reference Base.dll in the project giving error it got fixed. Now I have 15 different libraries where this dll is being referenced.
Can you suggest what I am doing wrong. 
Application is based on .Net 4.0

Note : I had this property from beginning

```
public  Dictionary<string,Base> Child {
        get { return _Child = _Child ?? new Dictionary<string, Base>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }
      set { _Child = value; }
    }
    protected Dictionary<string, Base> _Child;
```

Now I changed it like this

```
 public BOCollection<string, Base> Child
    {
        get { return _Child = _Child ?? new BOCollection<string, Base>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }
        set { _Child = value; }
    }
    protected BOCollection<string, Base> _Child;
```

Comment: Did you have a `Child` property in that class before?

Comment: Your indexer is not a problem. It says a property named `Child` was not found. Also why are you not using `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: Yes, I had this property from beginning. But why this will give problem. The property was before instance of Dictionary.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The property was before instance of Dictionary".

Comment: Don't reference DLLs, reference the project directly inside the solution. DLL versioning gets quite tricky if you do it manually.

Comment: When you make a Big Breaking Change like that, *always* increment the [AssemblyVersion].

Comment: There's also a problem with the `public new TValue this[TKey key]`. This means that to get to the indexer, you have to recompile everyone that depends on your assembly, because the old ones would still be calling the base classes indexer. `new` is not `override`.

Comment: @Luaan, Can you please elaborate your comment..

Comment: Yup, that's a breaking change indeed. No way to avoid recompilation of all the dependents :)

Comment: Well, if you cast `BOCollection<string, Base>` to `Dictionary<string, Base>` (valid, since `BOCollection` inherits from `Dictionary`), you're going to be using the indexer in `Dictionary`, not the new one you made. The method is not virtual and overriden, it's a new method defined in a derived type. You can't just change the return type of a property and expect the dependent assemblies to just work - you've changed the contract! This needs at least a recompilation, and in all likelyhood, many more changes to actually use your new code.

Comment: @Luaan, You mean in property I should cast it to Dictionary.

Comment: If you want to maintain compatibility without recompiling, yes. The problem is, since you're hiding the old indexer (`new` instead of `override`), using the indexer on a reference with the parent type will not call the new indexer - it's as if you didn't have `BOCollection` at all.

Comment: Is there any way I can override this indexer?

Comment: I'm affraid not. Those classes are not meant to be overriden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has many different issues, and there's no way to fix it without some changes to the dependent assemblies.

First, you've changed the contract (the return type of the `Child` property has changed) so you should really change the assembly version and recompile the dependents against your new assembly.

Second, you've hidden the indexer in your derived class. That will not do, because that means the indexer is used *only* when you refer to `BOCollection` specifically in code. Which means that if you don't change the code, 100% of your code will *not* use the version with a `lock` at all. That's incredibly unsafe design!

Third, use a `ConcurrentDictionary`. It gives you thread-safe access to the dictionary values out of the box :)

You're not going to avoid a recompilation of all the dependent assemblies, it's as simple as that. Now, if you're interested in future proofing, this is exactly one of the reasons you want to use as small interfaces as useful. For example, instead of using `Dictionary<string, Base>` as the return type, use `IDictionary<string, Base>`. This gives you the freedom to change the internal implementation without changing the contract, and thus breaking the DLL compatibility.

The only safe way to change the assembly without having to recompile its dependents is by avoiding any change that would be breaking. For example:

- Changing `const` or efault method parameters values - always a bad idea, because they're evaluated at compile time.
- Removing `public` or `protected` members
- Changing the return types or parameters of methods and properties

You *can* make some changes, though:

- Add new method overloads and new members
- Add new types
- Change pretty much any *code* - the important thing is not to change existing *definitions* (and even then, only those that are `public` and `protected`, and in some cases `internal`).

Even then, I'd mostly advise against it. It's usually a better idea to simply keep everything well synchronized, and versioned. It saves you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not that you've added an indexer, the problem is that you removed a property that is being used in other assemblies.

Those other assemblies still have code that intends to call the getter of the `Child` property, but since you removed it, that getter method is no longer there, and that's why you get that error.